# Run uglify js on windows

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I want to run this command from npm

```
./node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs dist/bundles/npm-module-seed.umd.js --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle --comments --output dist/bundles/npm-module-seed.umd.min.js
```

I get `.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

Omiting `./` gives : `node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same command should be working without providing the full path to uglifyjs. Use the package exposed commands instead, at the root of your project:

```
uglifyjs dist/bundles/npm-module-seed.umd.js --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle --comments --output dist/bundles/npm-module-seed.umd.min.js
```